# Why would the variable name being assigned _to_ affect the lookup of the value?

Tags: python, namespaces

In python, the following works fine:

```
def test_foo():
    class Foo(object):
        pass
    class Fam(object):
        bar = Foo

test_foo()
```

However the following fails with `NameError: name 'Foo' is not defined`:

```
def test_foo():
    class Foo(object):
        pass
    class Fam(object):
        Foo = Foo

test_foo()
```

Why does the name I'm assigning *to* affect the lookup of the value that's being assigned?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The mere fact that you assign to the name `Foo` inside the class definition makes the name `Foo` a local name in that scope (i.e. the scope of the class).  The local names are determined statically, during parsing and compiling to byte code.  When the execution reaches the statement

```
Foo = Foo
```

Python first evaluates the right-hand side.  It look ups the local name `Foo` -- as determined during compilation -- and fails to find it in the local scope.  Hence the error.

The same will happen if you'd try

```
def test_foo():
    foo = 3
    class A:
        bar = foo
        foo = 42

test_foo()
```

Comment: for clarity's sake, you might consider placing the above code in a `def test_foo():` block. When entered exactly as written (with `foo` in the module's global scope) this code generates no error!

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  Personally I find it annoying, but I'm sure there's a good reason for it.

Comment: @Singletoned: The main reason is speed:  Looking up local variables is much faster because the byte code already contains the information where to look for them.  This is why code often runs faster inside a function than in the global scope.